# how to remove + symbol from phone number using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to remove + symbol from the phone number and store the respective phone number in another variable.

```
class App extends Component {
this.state={
phone: '',
renumber: ''
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/api/phone')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
this.setState({phone: response.data}) //I want to remove + symbol from variable `phone - +78945612301` and then save it to `renumber variable - 78945612301`
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

withoutSign = () => {
let num = this.state.phone.replace('+', ' ') 
this.setState({renumber: num})
}

render(){
return(
<div>{this.state.phone} </div>
<div>{this.state.renumber} </div>
);
}
}
```

Can anyone help me in getting phone number without + symbol

Comment: Have you considered [replacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the '+' with ''?

Comment: you can use replace function, `'+78945612301'.replace('+', '')`

Comment: @RajKumar - Yes, i know we can give phone.replace('+', ' ') but the thing is how do i save in renumber variable. I have tried by writing function withoutSign = () => {let num = phone.replace('+', ' ') ; this.setState({renumber: num})}

Comment: It's unclear... do you want to convert the string "phone(+78945612301)" to "(78945612301)", or is it more like "+78945612301" to "78945612301". Please update question to include source data format and expected result. It's also necessary to include your code attempt at solving problem and details about what is or isn't working.

Comment: @DrewReese - Hi, I have updated the code. Could you please preview it ?

Comment: @Arunya, Does this solve your issue? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sandbox-class-component-tbquo  You just pass the phone number fetched from api as argument to another method and just do the replacement of text and setState to renumber..

Comment: @Arunya, Also the line which you have mentioned like ```this.state({phone: response.data})``` needs to be ```this.setState({phone: response.data})``` .. You need to use ```setState``` and not ```state``` ..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - It is setState, I have typed wrongly, In my code phone variable is working fine but could not get the value of renumber variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

- Initial state outside constructor is just a class instance, i.e. `state` vs `this.state`
- Convert `withoutSign` to consume a string and simply return the converted string value for inline use
- Setting state is `this.setState`

## Solution

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    phone: "",
    renumber: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/phone")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          phone: response.data,
          renumber: this.withoutSign(response.data),
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  withoutSign = phone => phone.replace("+", " ");

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.phone}</div>
        <div>{this.state.renumber}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit telephone number char replace]

Comment: Thanks for helping me :), this Works!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work and hope it will solve your problem

```
    withoutSign = () => {
       let num = this.state.phone.replace(/\+/g,"");
       this.setState({renumber: num})
    }
```